# Linq to XML: XML query results not populating DataGridView (.NET Windows Form app)

Tags: .net, datagridview, linq-to-xml

I'm kinda stuck.  I'm trying to get the results from my query (`Deposits`) to populate my `DataGridView` control (`dgvDeposits`).  I've tried:

```
dgvDeposits.Datasource = Deposits
```

It doesn't produce an error but no data is populated in the `DataGridView`.  What I expect is a list of deposits:  DepositID, DepositDate, DepositAmt.

Here is the code:

```
private void btnDeposits_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load("Portfolio.xml");
    var Deposits = from account in doc.Descendants("account")
        let deps = account.Element("deposits")
        let acct = account.Element("acct")
        where (string)account.Attribute("custid").Value == customerId
        select new
        {
            Depid = (string)account.Attribute("depid").Value,
            Amount = (string)account.Attribute("depamount").Value,
            Date = (string)account.Attribute("depdate").Value
        };
}
```

And here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<portfolio>
  <account>
    <acct custid="1" fname="Tommy" lname="Hawk" 
        ssn="928-329-1929" dob="4/6/1988"></acct>
    <deposits depid="1000" depdate="1/2/2011" depamount="1350.53"></deposits>
    <deposits depid="1003" depdate="2/3/2011" depamount="1377.81"></deposits>
    <deposits depid="1008" depdate="3/14/2011" depamount="84.00"></deposits>
    <withdrawals wdid="2001" wddate="1/31/2011" wdamount="80.00"></withdrawals>
    <withdrawals wdid="2005" wddate="4/8/2011" wdamount="80.00"></withdrawals>
    <withdrawals wdid="2007" wddate="6/1/2011" wdamount="2600.00"></withdrawals>
  </account>
  <account>
    <acct custid="2" fname="I. P." lname="Nightly" 
        ssn="457-23-4871" dob="6/1/1945"></acct>
    <deposits depid="1004" depdate="2/8/2011" depamount="741.22"></deposits>
    <deposits depid="1005" depdate="2/9/2011" depamount="47.00"></deposits>
    <deposits depid="1009" depdate="3/14/2011" depamount="89.99"></deposits>
    <withdrawals wdid="2003" wddate="3/1/2011" wdamount="55.00"></withdrawals>
    <withdrawals wdid="2004" wddate="3/3/2011" wdamount="28.00"></withdrawals>
    <withdrawals wdid="2006" wddate="4/8/2011" wdamount="450.00"></withdrawals>
  </account>
  <account>
    <acct custid="3" fname="Mary" lname="Echmass" 
        ssn="192-01-2933" dob="8/10/1973"></acct>
    <deposits depid="1002" depdate="1/15/2011" depamount="841.77"></deposits>
    <deposits depid="1006" depdate="2/14/2011" depamount="2170.00"></deposits>
    <deposits depid="1007" depdate="3/10/2011" depamount="21.01"></deposits>
    <withdrawals wdid="2002" wddate="1/16/2011" wdamount="700.00"></withdrawals>
    <withdrawals wdid="2008" wddate="6/3/2011" wdamount="24.00"></withdrawals>
    <withdrawals wdid="2009" wddate="6/30/2100" wdamount="38.46"></withdrawals>
  </account>  
</portfolio>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **acct** instead of **account** in where line and **dept** instead of **account** in the field initializer.

Moreover, I suspect it will return only the first **deposit** element for each **acct** element with the desired **custid** value, so probably only one element in total.

In order to return them all you can use a query like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("Portfolio.xml");
var Deposits = from account in doc.Descendants("account")
                  from deposit in account.Elements("deposits")
                  where (string)account.Element("acct").Attribute("custid").Value == customerId
                  select new
                     {
                        Depid = (string)deposit.Attribute("depid").Value,
                        Amount = (string)deposit.Attribute("depamount").Value,
                        Date = (string)deposit.Attribute("depdate").Value
                     };
```

Comment: I've added a sample of how you can return all the desposit nodes for the selected customer id.

Comment: No problem :). I'm happy I was able to help you :).

Answer (score 1):

You still didn't fix the error you had in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889656/linq-to-xml-xml-query-net-windows-form-app): you have to use `acct`, not `account` in your `where` and `select` clauses.